# British Railway Stations in ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm trying to use a ComoBox in VB.NET to list all of the GB railway stations for a user to select. However, of the 2553 stations, the String Collection Editor will not take more than about 1800 (mid way into R). Is there way to bypass this or will I have to use something else?

I also need the station code for the program as it needs to insert this into a URL to search for train tickets. I was thinking of adding the stations as 'Acle ACL' (Station Name Station Code) and then somehow using the last three digits in the combobox for the URL.

[The station codes can be found here](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/48541.aspx)

So if anyone can help with the combobox restriction problem that would be excellent. Also any tips with the station codes would be brilliant too but I should be able to manage.

Comment: Not really a good user interface choice. Do you really expect that your users scroll a list of 2553 names to select the last station in the combo?

Comment: Hi, I agree! I thought that if one started tying in the name of the station the relevant ones would appear in the combo box. Is there a component that perform such a task? Is there some way I could use the spreadsheet directly to search instead perhaps?

Comment: What kind of application we are talking about? ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF ?

Comment: You need to create custom control. Design it so that users can easily search by narrowing down their choices

Answer (score 0):

Populating Combobox with 2553 is not seem to user friendly.
Instead of that you can use AutoCompleteTextbox , which can suggest stations to user as they type in into textbox.

Here is the sample for this ,
[AutoComplete-Textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243368/AutoComplete-Textbox)